# Temperature converter with JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript

I'm a total beginner with JavaScript. I'm trying to get this temp converter to work, but get confused on what need to be called. Why is this code not working?

```
     var convertCtoF = document.getElementById("degC");
 convertCtoF.onchange = function(degC){ 
                var degreesC = document.getElementById("degC").value; 

                var degreesF = (("degC" * 9/5)+ (32)); 

                document.getElementById("degFOut").innerHTML = degreesF;
 }

 var convertFtoC = document.getElementById("degF");
 convertFtoC.onchange = function(degF){  
                var degreesF = document.getElementById("degF").value; 

                var degreesC = (("degF" - 32) * (5/9)); 

                document.getElementById("degCOut").innerHTML = degreesC;
 }
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example so that we can re-create the problem you're having. Also, post the errors you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be:

```
var convertCtoF = document.getElementById("degC");
    convertCtoF.onchange = function(degC){
    var degreesC = document.getElementById("degC").value; 
    var degreesF = ((degreesC * 9/5)+ (32));
    document.getElementById("degFOut").innerHTML = degreesF;
}

var convertFtoC = document.getElementById("degF");
    convertFtoC.onchange = function(degF){
    var degreesF = document.getElementById("degF").value; 
    var degreesC = ((degreesF - 32) * (5/9));
    document.getElementById("degCOut").innerHTML = degreesC;
}
```

You are referencing the variable, not a string.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work by referencing the variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
var degreesF = ((degreesC * 9/5)+ (32));
```

...

```
var degreesC = ((degreesF - 32) * (5/9));
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed fast was

```
(("degC" * 9/5)+ (32));
```

and

```
(("degC" * 9/5)+ (32));
```

Multiplying a [String](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp) by a [Number](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_number.asp) will return NaN. What I think you meant to do was use the variables you defined above each of those lines.

So for example...

```
var degreesC = document.getElementById("degC").value; 
var degreesF = ((degreesC * 9/5)+ (32));
```

You should probably take the arguments for those onchange functions out, because they are not being used. Other than that, I think it would help to provide all relevant code (including HTML), so that we can assist you further.